# How to get Drop-Down Box Options window instead of Code View in Word 2003

Tags: microsoft-word-2003

I am creating a form in Word 2003.  When I create a drop-down (combo box) and double click on it, I get the MS Visual Basic editor, rather than the Drop-Down Form-Field Options dialog.

How can I get this back?

Answer (score 0):

I had the Control Toolbox toolbar open instead of the Forms toolbar.  This inserts the Active X type form elements onto the page which have different controls.